# delete item in a list c#

Tags: c#, linq, list, memory-management

I need a little help. I have 2 lists in my project: 1 has 5,000 items, `listA`, and the other has 10,000 items, `listB`. I am reading the list using a `for loop`:

```
for(int j = 5000 - 1; j > 0; j--)
```

I need to delete the last item in `listA`,and in `listB`, I need to delete the last 2 items. This process is necessary because I need to optimize memory in my software.

i really appreciate any help Thanks

I tried to do this, but it doesn't work:

```
listA.RemoveAt(j);
listB.RemoveAt(9999 - i + 1);
listB.RemoveAt(9999 - i );
```

Comment: You probably meant `9999 - (i + 1)`, or `9999 - i - 1`.

Comment: If you're just removing items from your list why do you need to iterate them?

Comment: btw, you're currently reading one too few items - you need `j >= 0` for a reverse loop

Comment: Do you explicitly have to use a for loop in this situation (a homework assignment, for example)? Because there are far easier ways to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: do you really have to do a for loop for a specific logic? or only remove the last item from List A and List B?

Comment: might want to clean up ambiguity of `i` and `j` in question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To delete the last item do

```
listA.RemoveAt(listA.Count - 1)
```

For the last two items simply execute it twice. You should check though wether the count is already 0, otherwise you'll get an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Since `j` seems to always be equal to the index of the last item in `listA`, `2 * j + 1` is always equal to the index of the last item in `listB`. So you could just use [`RemoveAt`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cw9x18z.aspx) / [`RemoveRange`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y33yd2b5.aspx):

```
listA.RemoveAt(j);
listB.RemoveRange(2 * j, 2);
```

Also, if memory management is a big concern you might want to consider shrinking your list after a while by setting the [`Capacity`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y52x03h2.aspx) (note that this can have performance impacts so you should avoid doing this too eagerly).

```
listA.Capacity = j;
listB.Capacity = 2 * j;
```